# Are there examples of integers m, n ≥ 2 for which $Z_m$ ∩ $Z_n$ = ∅?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

> Are there examples of integers m, n ≥ 2 for which $Z_m$ ∩ $Z_n$ = ∅?

The answer is as follows:

> If m, n ≥ 2 and m $\neq$ n, then Zm ∩ Zn = ∅. For example, Z2 ∩ Z3 =
> ∅.

$Z_3$ = {0,1,2}, $Z_2$ = {0,1}. So isn't their intersection {0,1}?

**More details:**

The preceeding questions are as follows:

> 9.60. For integers m, n ≥ 2 consider $Z_m$ and $Z_n$. Let [a] ∈ $Z_m$ where 0 ≤ a ≤ m − 1. Then a, a + m ∈ [a] in $Z_m$.
> If a, a + m ∈ [b] for some [b] ∈ $Z_n$, then what can be said of m and n?

> 9.61. **(a)** For integers m, n ≥ 2 consider $Z_m$ and $Z_n$. If some element of $Z_m$ also belongs to $Z_n$, then what can be said of $Z_m$ and $Z_n$?
> **(b)** Are there examples of integers m, n ≥ 2 for which $Z_m$ ∩ $Z_n$ = ∅?

Comment: Generally it doesn't make (algebraic) sense to consider the intersection of two rings unless they are subrings of some larger ring - which is not the case for your quotient ring interpretation of the notation. What is the source of the question?

Comment: @BillDubuque added the preceeding connected questions

Comment: Apparently, with $Z_m$ here the set of classes (not representations) is meant. And then in fact, $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_3$ have no intersection : For example $1$ in $\mathbb Z_2$ is the set of numbers of the form $2n+1$ , whereas $1$ in $\mathbb Z_3$ is the set of numbers of the form $3n+1$ which is a different set. But this is a strange way to define the intersection.

Comment: @Peter Thank you!